# Add multiple static roles to power BI [RLS]

Tags: powerbi

I have about hounded something roles (to be used by RLS - Row Level Security) to be defined in single power BI report. Is there any more effective option than using "Manage roles" feature? Adding one by one works but takes too much time.

Comment: No, there is no other way.

Comment: that is really bad @AndreyNikolov :( it is hard to manage when you have many roles